# Run command in Container for Linux during Azure Devops Pipeline Release

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

Currently I'm deploying my docker image into AppService for Linux from AzureDevops. I want to run some migrations before the container became fully available.

The db migrations are executed by calling a cli command in my container. How can I achieve this from DevOps pipeline?

1. Is there a way to SSH to the specific *not fully deployed* container?
2. Is there a way run a cli command without configuring SSH?
3. Is there any other recommended way for migrations/running some scripts before making the container available?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose you have 2 options:

1. run some sort of init script that does the migrations and then starts the web server\what have you process that's actually doing the work
2. modifying entrypoint\command that the container runs by default, so it does that on its own ([dockerfile reference](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#run)).

something like this:

```
RUN /bin/bash -c 'run migrations; run payload'
```

Comment: Thanks, this is something I know and wanted to do, but AppService for Containers injects my envs configuration secrets after running the init command. But probably the best will be to rework downloading the secrets from KeyVault and do the migration in the init.

Comment: so, the answer to the first 2 question is "no", as far as I know

Comment: I've realized the injected settings is available also during init command. My previous attempts were somehow buggy. I'm saved.

Answer (score 1):

We achieved this by modification of container entrypoint. We do not care much about the execution of migration from multiple containers simultaneously, it is handled by the migration framework.

```sh
#!/bin/bash

set -e

if [[ -n $MIGRATION_ONSTART ]]; then
    ( su -s /bin/bash -c "/var/www/bin/console migration:continue" www-data &)
fi

exec "$@"
```

Comment: Thanks, this is something I know and wanted to do, but AppService for Containers injects my envs configuration secrets after running the init command. But probably the best will to rework downloading the secrets from KeyVault and do the migration in the init.

Comment: I've realized the injected settings is available also during init command. My previous attempts were somehow buggy. I'm saved.